# Eclipse plugin installation from Project File

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

I want to install eclipse plugin Agilereview from following link:

https://github.com/AgileReview-Project/AgileReview-EclipsePlugin

I downloaded the zip and unzipped it. I added it in eclipse as project and many projects added into workspace. When I tried to select all those projects and export them as deploy-able plugins in eclipse repository, eclipse doesn't allow it and always show error like plugin file missing. A problem is the zip file include many folders and many of those folder has its own plugin.xml file. Therefore, I think this Agilereview plugin itself is a combination of many plugins. I am sure that plugin is okay and its my mistake to install it.

Can anyone tell me, what is the mistake I am doing while installation? I want to install this plugin manually since later I need to optimize it.

Comment: Hi. While we'd love to help, the information you have provided is simply not enough. What did you try, what error messages did you get exactly, and all that kind of information would be helpful.

Comment: Hello, thanks for being so nice. As you can see, I added all the folders, that you will get after unzip, as the projects in workspace. The only way I know to install plugin from workspace is export as deployed plugins and I tried it. Normally, eclipse deploy it and install the plugin in repository. But in this case, because there are many plugins that needed to be installed together, Eclipse is showing error, like one of the plugins are missing, although I included it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the folders `org.agilereview.xxx` is a separate Eclipse project. So you should use 'Import > Existing Projects into Workspace' to import these projects.

Since there are `pom.xml` files it looks like you should use maven and tycho to build the code.

Comment: Sorry not my area I just know that `pom.xml` means maven. There are Eclipse maven and tycho plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For building RCP applications and plugins like Agilereview, which itself is a combination of many projects, you can check out the following tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

Eclipsetycho provides support for building eclipse components.

Install the maven eclipse tool, which will make your work easy.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

This is a pretty complex process, so spend some time to learn from the tutorial.